# FatalErrorException in routes.php line 22: Class 'Painting' not found

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I got this error when I was trying to learn Laravel migrations from a video tutorial. The tutor created a file named **Painting.php** in the **app/models** folder. The content of **Painting.php** is:

```
<?php

    class Painting extends Eloquent{

    }
?>
```

and then in the **routes.php**:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
     $painting = new Painting; //**this thing generates error**
     $painting->title='Do no wrong';
     $painting->save();

    return view('welcome');
});
```

Now , question is where I am supposed to place **Painting.php** file since there is no **models** folder in Laravel 5.1?

Comment: It sounds like the video series you’re following uses Laravel 4.*, and you are working with a Laravel 5.1 app. You’ll find a lot of things have changed in Laravel from versions 4 to 5, including the introduction of namespaces and a change in the directory structure. You’d be better off finding Laravel 5-specific tutorials if you’re trying to learn the framework.

Comment: @MartinBean I think you are right :) , can you suggest best place to learn laravel 5?

Comment: Laracasts is pretty much the de facto place to learn Laravel, and is regularly updated with Laravel and general programming tutorials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a namespace for `Painting` class:

```
<?php
namespace App;

class Painting extends Eloquent {}
```

And an use statement in **routes.php**:

```
<?php
use App\Painting;
```

This scenario assumes **Painting.php** resides in the **app** folder.

Answer (score 0):

**The following changes made will make your code work**
**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**Painting.php**

```
<?php 
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Painting extends Model
{

}
```

**/routes/web.php**

```
<?php

use App\Painting;


Route::get('/', function () {

  $painting = new Painting;
  $painting->title = 'Its Your Wish';
  $painting->artist = 'Working Fine';
  $painting->year = 2017;
  $painting->save();

  return view('welcome');
});
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to explain the essential parts of the answer and possibly what was the problem with OPs code.