# Class 'Painting' not found in web.php Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

Hi all I'm a newbie for Laravel when I try to insert data to the table paintings which worked fine up-to this point now the browser throwing (1/1) `FatalErrorException Class 'Painting' not found in web.php` (line 15)
Hoping kind help from you . Thanks!

**Here is web.php**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    $painting = new Painting; //line 15
    $painting->title = 'Do No Wronge';
    $painting->artist = 'D. DoRight';
    $painting->year = 2017;
    $painting->save();
    return view('welcome');
});
```

**Here is Painting.php in app folder**

```
<?php

namespace App;

class Painting extends Eloquent
{

}
?>
```

Even the [FatalErrorException in routes.php line 22: Class 'Painting' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31358101) doesn't provided the correct answer for the version i'm using

Comment: do you have an `use` statement in `web.php`, such as `use App\Painting;` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FatalErrorException in routes.php line 22: Class 'Painting' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31358101/fatalerrorexception-in-routes-php-line-22-class-painting-not-found)

Comment: You should include the model in your controller,

Comment: @AlexAndrei after adding `use App\Painting` in `web.php` then this comes
Class 'App\Eloquent' not found
in Painting.php (line 6)

anything i must include inside the class?

Comment: Assuming you are using the latest version of laravel, check out the docs here on how to define your model https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#defining-models. Basically you need to have an `use` statement in your model also. After the namespace declaration put this `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;`

Comment: also it seems to me that you are following a tutorial based on laravel 4

Comment: yes you are correct i added Eloquent\Model then it worked haha yup following the lynda video which uses laravel 4

Thanks gentleman!

Comment: put it as an answer i can select

Answer (score 0):

**Modified files [Working solution]**

Here is **web.php**

```
<?php
use App\Painting;

Route::get('/', function () {
  $painting = new Painting; //line 15
  $painting->title = 'Do No Wronge';
  $painting->artist = 'D. DoRight';
  $painting->year = 2017;
  $painting->save();
  return view('welcome');
});
```

Here is **Painting.php** in app folder

```
<?php 
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Painting extends Model
{

}
```